# Regex returning blank output Hive

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I am designing a regex to matches one of the following three structures:

Pseudo code:

```
number.number.number.number e.g. 102.100.1.1
number.number.number e.g. 1.2.4
number.number. e.g. 1.2
```

The regex I have so far looks like this:

```
\d{1,3}\\.\d{1,3}\\.\d{1,3}\\.\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}\\.\d{1,3}\\.\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}\\.\d{1,3}}
```

I am running the following query to test this:

```
select 
    regexp_extract('172.1.1.1', '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}') 
from 
    dual
```

[Regex101 suggests this should work](https://regex101.com/r/wH1oT3/1), [as does RegExr](http://regexr.com/3asdj).

However, the result is blank. What is being overlooked on here and why doesn't this work?

Comment: It is highly possible you need to double-escape slashes. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF. "Note that some care is necessary in using predefined character classes: using '\s' as the second argument will match the letter s; '\\s' is necessary to match whitespace, etc."

Comment: First thing I tried. I have tried both escaping all slashes( \), and escaping only slash dot (\.) Neither seem to work either and return blank
select 
    regexp_extract('172.1.1.1', '\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}') 
from 
    dual



 select 
    regexp_extract('172.1.1.1', '\d{1,3}\\.\d{1,3}\\.\d{1,3}\\.\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}\\.\d{1,3}\\.\d{1,3}|\\{1,3}\\.\d{1,3}') 
from 
    dual

Comment: Add the index parameter (3rd one) set to `0`. Does it change the outcome?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Still stumped.

Comment: Try `REGEX_EXTRACT('172.1.1.1', '(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})', 1);`, or `regexp_extract_all('172.1.1.1', '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')` to get all matches.

Comment: This matches:

select regexp_extract('172.1.1.1', '(\\d{1,3})(\\.)(\\d{1,3})(\\.)(\\d{1,3})(\\.)(\\d{1,3})|(\\d{1,3})(\\.)(\\d{1,3})(\\.)(\\d{1,3})|(\\{1,3})(\\.)(\\d{1,3})',0)

Your advice about including the index helped, as well as the double escape slashes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because you use '\\.' instead of '\.'. With '\\.', it searches for the following pattern: "\." instead of ".".

Try this:

```
\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){1,3}
```

EDIT:

You should also think to add delimiters to your regex.
With this regex, it will get "234.567" if run on "1234.5678".
This can easily be fixed with this:

```
(^|[^\d])(\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){1,3})($|[^\d])
```

And then get only the second group from the output

Comment: Thanks for the advice - unfortunately in this instance, this doesn't work and the '\\.' is necessary. I now have this working thanks to the suggestions above about using the index and double backslashing.